# Plotting with discontinuous axis in matlab

Tags: matlab, plot, axis, break

I need to plot some data in matlab, and to better show the details I'm interested in, I want both a break and two different resolutions in the x axis. Hard to explain, but let me illustrate:

x x x x //  x  x  x  x

1 2 3 4 // 10 20 30 40

I've found plenty of examples of creating a break in the x-axis, but nothing for changing axis mid-plot. I'd really prefer to do this without changing the data, such as by interpolating etc. Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: You might find [this contribution on the Matlab FileExchange](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/3683-breakxaxis) to be what you are looking for.